# Moved Azure Subscription and now Resources are Lost

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, transfer

I have two accounts, me@gmail.com and me@my-company.com. Both accounts are billing me. I created a VM, with storage, and network in me@gmail.com and under subscription "Me Personal". I was testing the movement, after planning, etc to the other account (Company AD) but my other subscription "Firstname MI Lastname". I lost my Roles, no custom roles, VM contained $HOME/payload.txt "hello world", and I "Changed Directories" using the option at the top of the Subscription blade. I selected "Firstname MI Lastname", no errors, saw the subscription was gone and then went to the company account (my billing) and ...

I selected the subscription "Firstname MI Lastname" and NO resource group, NO VM, NO storage, no resources. I looked at all resources and the moved resources are nowhere to be found.

Can someone help me find these resources? My expectation was that because the subscription was light, simple VM, hard drive, and network would just simply move across the same region and the machine and disk would just show up under the new/existing subscription along with it's resource group parent.

Thanks in advance for any reply.

David

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this question. I'm not sure about the two directories in my Google (gmail) account. Anyhow, I found that the resource group did move across subscriptions under another directory. This directory was not AD Default but my Firstname MI and Lastname just like the one in my company account. Under my initial account, I selected the Settings icon and saw the other directory.

And, because it was in this account, that is why it was shown in the dropdown when I selected "Change Directory" in the Subscription overview.

I still have to determine how to test the entire transfer from one tenant to the other, including the billing.

Comment: Moving subscription into new tenant is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/transfer-subscription Loosing custom roles, RBAC etc are documented. Transferring billing is different process: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/billing-subscription-transfer